# How get last item pushed to a RxJs/BehaviorSubject by value?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am using rxjs in a project, the problem I face is that both `myBehaviorSubject.value` and `myBehaviorSubject.getValue()` returns the last item pushed into the observable by reference. Can I somehow get that last item by value?

Note: I know I can copy the object with `Object.assign` but that seems like boilerplate code to me. I am looking for some official method or piece of code what extends it to support this functionality. So what I want to do is something like `myBehaviorSubject.getValueByValue()` (Sounds strange, I know.)

Comment: I doubt there is something like this already in rx. But you can always extend `BehaviorSubject` or even monkeypatch its prototype. `BehaviorSubject.prototype.cloneValue = function() {
    return Object.assign({}, this.getValue())
  }` http://plnkr.co/edit/dTUjGi6TAfJtk36Qvqo0?p=preview

Comment: how could there be built in functionality for this?  Do you want a shallow copy?  Or deep copy?  Something in between?  Does your object have circular references?  There are too many variations.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is nothing in rxjs that does this, and this isn't really in the Rx domain. While observables work best when used with immutable types, rxjs doesn't provide any features in this area. For simple object cloning you can, as you suggest, use something like Object.assign. For collections, I recommend immutable.js. You can (as suggested in the comments) extend BehaviorSubject yourself to include whichever implementation you prefer.